# TLS and authentication for RPC

Tags: security, rpc

TLS and authentication for RPC has been completed in the Monero dev branch for [quite some time](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4atg0d/monero_rpc_no_password/d13bo2p). Has it been reworked to fully address any conflicts with net_skeleton's license so that it will be ready to merge to master along with the OMQ branch when ready?

Once TLS and authentication for RPC is merged are there any changes a security conscious exchange should make to the setup in the diagram below?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dev branch has been canned, and the 0MQ effort is being refactored / partially rewritten by `tewinget`. Unfortunately the `net_skeleton` licensing issue isn't one we can work around, as far as we can tell, so we are actively looking at an alternative. Note that you can, right now, stick something like nginx in front of it to handle both authentication and TLS, and use nginx's `proxy_pass` to reverse proxy the RPC calls. In fact, this may be a preferable route for a security-conscious exchange, as nginx can provide fine-grained control over user access, TLS cipher suites, and so on.